# How to prevent background scrolling when displaying popup in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**How to prevent background scrolling when displaying popup in selenium webdriver?**

***Scenario*:**

One pop is opened and I have to perform some operations/actions on it, but immediately if I click the field in the pop, the page scrolls in the background and my pop up scrolls up and becomes invisible for selenium for any interactions.

***Expected:***

1. I clicked on a button
2. A pop-up window is opened
3. I have to add some texts and select some values
4. then close
5. but these I cannot perform since the background scrolls and pop up is also scrolled to top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is scroll the field into the viewport using `JavascriptExecutor` before entering any text into the textbox.Look at below example.

```
//After modal window is opened
WebElement txtBox = driver.findElement(By.css("input[type='text']")); //textBoxPresent in popup 
txtBox.click(); //now the background will scroll to top.
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",txtBox); // this will scroll the textbox to the view port hence available for selenium to interact
txtBox.sendKeys("someText");
```

Comment: I am getting "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguemts is not defined"

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0].scrolIntoView is not a function

Comment: Or how to stop background scrolling when any pop up window is opened?

Comment: Fine!! Glad it worked. Don't forget to accept the answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to handle this scenario:-

1. You can disable the background scroll, if a popup is there on the screen. You just have to set the property `overflow = hidden`, you can achieve the same using `JavascriptExecutor`
2. Once you are able to launch the pop-up, you can just scroll the pop up into the view, so that Webdriver is able to identify the element without throwing `Exceptions`, this also you can achieve using `JavascriptExecutor`